# What is the difference between "!window" and "!!window"?

Tags: html, event-handling, addeventlistener, web-worker

I know my question is a bit vague but really like to know a bit more. Thanks in advance. Just need a good, quick and easy run down of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`!window` and `!!window` are both boolean values in JavaScript. The `!` operator will first convert the expression to is  boolean form (see this gist about [Implicit Boolean Conversions in JavaScript](https://gist.github.com/lucastan/5420685)).

`!window` is the inverse of that, it evaluates to `true` if and only if the `window` variable is either undefined or is defined to a 'falsy' value.

`!!window` is a variable that evaluates to `true` if and only if a `window` global variable is defined to a truthy value (false otherwise).

Comment: Thanks, perfect explanation for me.